# Как сделать чтобы рандом выдавал сначала больше повторяющих чисел?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Как сделать чтобы рандом выдавал сначала больше повторяющих чисел

к примеру 001000111100000110001111110001111110010001110111
и потом через период выдавал больше одинарних

00110001010101001100101101010100111010

Comment: Т.к. это уже не рандом, то придётся писать свою функцию.

Comment: разный вес. К примеру, на Питоне: `print(*[int(random.random() < 0.3) for _ in range(20)])`

Comment: @jfs: Это создаст перевес _единиц_, в то время как ТС хочет перевес _повторений_.

Comment: @VladD: верно. Моя ошибка: нолики крупнее выглядят и я почему то решил, что их больше ожидается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужен нестандартный генератор случайных бит, который помнит предыдущий бит, и выдаёт результат, зависимый от него.

Это легко организовать:

```
class DependentRandomBitGenerator
{
    Random r = new Random();
    public double DependencyFactor { get; set; } = 0.5;
    int prev = 0;
    public int GetNext()
    {
        if (r.NextDouble() < DependencyFactor)
            prev = 1 - prev;
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
var rg = new DependentRandomBitGenerator() { DependencyFactor = 0.2 };
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    Console.Write(rg.GetNext());
Console.WriteLine();
rg.DependencyFactor = 0.8;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    Console.Write(rg.GetNext());
Console.WriteLine();
```

Результат:

```
0000000011111100000000001
0010101011010101010101010
```

Вы можете, по идее, плавно менять вероятность «сцепки» последовательных бит.

Comment: Ошибка `(1,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DependentRandomGenerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @KillNoise: Ну опечатался, `DependentRandomBitGenerator`.

Comment: Думал, думал, какой бы лучше функцией менять фактор, и ничего кроме `2 * Math.atan(coeff * i) / Math.PI` в голову не приходит... Можно её ещё в степень возводить, для крутости/пологости=)

Comment: @selya; Ага, арктангенс — красиво, да.

Comment: можете это запихать в одну функцию например `rand` и чтобы она видавала по одном значении за один раз?

Comment: @KillNoise: То есть вы хотите, чтобы подгонка `DependencyFactor`'а выполнялась автоматически?

Comment: @VladD, не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду под видом "автоматически". Хочу получать числа поодиночке `0`, `0`, `0`..., а не все сразу типа `0000000011111100000000001`

Comment: @VladD, знаете как решить ?

Comment: @KillNoise: Ну так не вызывайте `GetNext` в цикле. Код же выдаёт числа по одному, и печатает их в цикле.

Comment: @VladD, заработало, спасибо большое )